# charからstrに変換するには

Tags: rust

rustでcharからstringに変換するメソッドは用意されていますが、charからstrに変換するメソッドはありますか？

Answer (score 3):

エンコードした文字`a`を格納するための配列`b`を用意し、文字`a`の`encode_utf8`メソッドの引数として配列`b`を使うことで、配列`b`を指す`&mut str`の変数に変換することができます。

```
fn main() {
    let c = 'a'; // 文字'a'

    let mut b = [0; 4]; // 文字を格納するための配列b

    let s = c.encode_utf8(&mut b); // 配列bにUTF8にエンコードした文字cを格納し、bを指す&mut strのsを返す

    println!("{}", s); // 文字'a'が表示される
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=64fff54aa8de6d71a3b07c6276f051c6

`encode_utf8`メソッドについて
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.encode_utf8

Answer (score 2):

ちょっと調べてみたのですが不可能そうです。

[リファレンス](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/types/textual.html#textual-types)によるとStringはUTF-8なのに対してcharはUTF-32でエンコードされています。

[UTF-32、UTF-16、UTF-8 の相互変換](https://qiita.com/benikabocha/items/e943deb299d0f816f161)という記事を見てもらうとわかりやすいと思うですが、エンディアンの違いを抜きにしてもUTF-32はUTF-8のコードポイントを単に4バイトにした形にはなっていないので、メモリ上に参照すべき文字列がないということになります。つまりstrは作成できないということです。
実際、標準ライブラリでもそのようなAPIは見当たりません。

メモリ確保が嫌でしたら、[ArrayString](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/0.5.1/arrayvec/struct.ArrayString.html)に[push](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/0.5.1/arrayvec/struct.ArrayString.html#method.push)するのが目的に合うかもしれません。

Comment: itok01さんの方法のほうが外部ライブラリ依存がなくてよさそうですね